# How would you find the roots of $x^3-3x-1 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I'm not too sure how to tackle this problem. Supposedly, the roots of the equation are $2\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{9}\right),-2\cos\left(\frac {2\pi}{9}\right)$ and $-2\cos\left(\frac {4\pi}{9}\right)$

How do I start? The Cosines seem especially scary...

Comment: What have you done? Have you tried doing any research on how to solve cubics? This can be solved using [Vieta's substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Vieta.27s_substitution), although the answer will not be in the form of $b\cos A$ like you want.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: You wouldn't... finding the exact solution, especially in the form of trig functions, is not general knowledge. If you're expected to be able to solve this, then you must have recently learned something directly applicable....

Comment: Oh no, my friend gave me a "challenge" problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=t+t^{-1}$ in $y=x^3-3x-1$. So we have $$\left(t+\frac {1}{t}\right)^{3}-3\left(t+\frac {1}{t}\right)-1=0$$

Expanding that and simplifying, we get $\frac {t^{6}-t^{3}+1}{t^{3}}$ and multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $(t^3+1)$ we get $\frac {t^{9}+1}{t^{3}(t^{3}+1)}$.

We let $t=\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)$ and we get $\cos(9\alpha)+i\sin(9\alpha)=-1$. Equating terms, we get $$\begin{cases}\cos(9\alpha)=-1\\\sin(9\alpha)=0\end{cases}$$

From there, we see that $\alpha=\frac {2k\pi+\pi}{9}$ for $k=0,2,3\ldots$ We want the real part so we have $$e^{\frac {2k\pi+\pi}{9}i}+e^{-\frac {2k\pi+\pi}{9}i}=2\cos\left(\frac {2k\pi+\pi}{9}\right)$$ for $k=0,2,3\ldots$

---

You could also use Vieta's trigonometric formula to find the roots.

Given the equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, one can find the roots by finding $p$ and $q$ where $$p=\frac {3b-a^2}{9}$$$$q=\frac {9ab-27c-2a^3}{54}$$
The roots are given in $$\begin{cases}x_1=2\sqrt{-p}\cos\left(\frac {\theta}{3}\right)-\frac {a}{3}\\x_2=2\sqrt{-p}\cos\left(\frac {\theta+2\pi}{3}\right)-\frac {a}{3}\\x_3=2\sqrt{-p}\cos\left(\frac {\theta+4\pi}{3}\right)-\frac {a}{3}\end{cases}$$
where $\cos\left(\frac {\theta}{3}\right)=\frac {q}{\sqrt{-p^3}}$.

Answer (score 9):

HINT:

Let $x=b\cos A$

$$\implies b^3\cos^3A-3(b\cos A)=1$$

As $\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A,$

$$\dfrac43=\dfrac{b^3}{3b}\implies b^2=4\text{  as }b\ne0$$

Let $b=2$

Consequently, $$2\cos3A=1\iff\cos3A=\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3$$

$$3A=2n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3=\dfrac\pi3(6n\pm1)$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$A=\dfrac\pi9(6n\pm1)$$ where $n\equiv0,\pm1\pmod3$

What if $b=-2 :)$