# Solve the classic third degree equation

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, math-history, cubics

Find $x$ such that
$$x^3-6x^2-3x+2=0.$$

Solution: Classical cubic resolution gives three real solutions
$\boxed{2+\sqrt{20}\cos\frac{2k\pi+\arccos\sqrt\frac 45}3,k=0,1,2}$

(write $x=2+\sqrt{20}\cos t$)

I have heard that this was a method that came from Abel or Galois. Is it true or I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [Depressed cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic)

$$y=x-2\iff x=y+2$$

$$0=(y+2)^3-6(y+2)^2-3(y+2)+2=y^3-15y-20$$

Use [How would you find the roots of $x^3-3x-1 = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824431/how-would-you-find-the-roots-of-x3-3x-1-0/1824438#1824438)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with either Abel or Galois. The trigonometric way of solving cubic equations, when they have three real roots, is due to Viète.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#History) identifies François Viète (or Vieta) as having originally derived the trigonometric formula for cubic equations with three real roots.

The solution itself is correct.

Comment: OK @bernard, how do you get the special c character and that accent over the e?  I have only standard English language lettering.  Thanks.

Comment: A French keyboard  has the c with cedilla (that's the technical name of this diacritic) and the é, which makes it quite easy. On a Qwerty keyboard, you can see [this link](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-type-french-accents-1372770) or [this one](https://www.languedoc121tech.fr/french-accented-characters-qwerty/).