# Show $p\in(1,2)$ is a fixed point

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Given the iteration $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{3x_n+1}$ show that $p\in(1,2)$ is a fixed point

$$x=\sqrt[3]{3x+1}\iff f(x)=x^3-3x-1$$

Plugging in $1$ result in $-3$ whereas $2$ gives $1$ so there is a root in this interval, but how can I be sure that there is a fixed point and not just a root?

Comment: A root of $f$ *is* a fixed point of the iteration (as you correctly derived).

Comment: @MartinR So there is a root at $(1,2)$ therefore there is a fixed point there?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824431/how-would-you-find-the-roots-of-x3-3x-1-0/1824438#1824438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed point is the real root of  $x^3-3x-1=0$, we can show that this Eq. has one real root in $(1,2)$. It follows by Intermediate theorem as $f(1)f(2)=-3<0$, So the given cubic has one real root in (1,2) and it can be found numerically as 1.8793...